# Apache Spark reading UTF-16 CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to read a CSV file encoded in UTF-16.

```
val test = spark.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.option("delimiter",";")
.option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
.option("encoding", "UTF-16")
.option("charset", "ISO-8859-1")
.load("...")
```

As a result I get extra lines:

[image]

Is it possible that Spark can only work with UTF-8 encoding? Or there is some other way to read UTF-16 CSV into a dataframe?

Comment: what bout recoding input file using iconv ?

Comment: What happens when you leave out the `charset` option?

Comment: @VictorGubin We have some special characters in on of the columns, and when exporting from db we have to use Unicode(UTF-16).

Comment: @ErnestKiwele this error: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 177.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 177.0 (TID 10232, 10.54.240.239, executor 0): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @StStojanovic Please share some sample file content that can be used to reproduce it...

Comment: @StStojanovic I mean, take your file exported from BD and simply recode from command line like  `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8  com.databricks.spark.csv >> com.databricks.spark.csv.utf8.csv` UTF-8 supports all possible UNICODE characters, including 1-4 bytes.

Comment: What is the spark version?  If 2.x, you can try with [`.format("csv")`](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/migrating-to-spark-two-part-2/). The databricks spark-csv connector [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/TextFile.scala) seems doubtful when using any other format than the default UTF-8.

Comment: @datahack Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Anybody figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing a similar issue while trying to read a csv file having UTF-16 format.

I am using mac and I didn't knew what is the encoding of the csv file that I was reading. Initially I was reading the file without providing any option for encoding and it was giving me two '?' in front of the column name.

So tried to find out the encoding of the csv file that I was reading by using below command in my mac.

```
file -I yourFile
```

The output of this command showed me that the encoding of the file is `charset=utf-16le`

Now I am reading the file by providing this options and it works fine.

```
val df = spark.read.
            format("csv").
            option("quote", "\"").
            option("escape", "\\").
            option("multiLine", "true").
            option("inferSchema", "true").
            option("header","true").
            option("encoding", "UTF-16").
            load(sourceS3path)
```

There is no needing of providing the option of charset if it is just reading the UTF-16 file.